# Modifying Caret with img overlay

Tags: html, css, sass, pseudo-element

I have a simple container with a triangle caret appended at the bottom.

```
<div class="home" id="hero">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="hero-text">
      Welcome to the <br>
      Lorem Ipsum Akinator
    </h1>
    <p class="sub-text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam voluptua.
    </p>
    <div class="home_sign_up">
    </div>
    <div class="img"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="arrow-down"></div> <!-- CARET -->
```

My home div has an image, and I need that image to be extended over the caret but ONLY in there.

Give it a a look -> [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/117126).

I tried a lot of things, I'm missing something.
I'm even thinking that my approach is bad. Basically what I'm trying to do is, to simply add that triangle at the bottom mid with the image overlaying it.

Basically it's this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 ways to go:

1. reuse the main div image in the caret

   1a. set/position it in a border-image

   1b. cut out a partial transparent part of the main image and use that
      to shape your caret
2. create the cutout for the caret from the main div

   2a. adding divs inside the main div, at its bottom, so they cover a part of the image

   2b. make a transparent cutout in the image, shaped with a caret in the bottom

Answer 1a/2a is done with css settings, 1b/2b can be done automatically using server side code (ASP/PHP)